# How to not start an EmberJs App with static assets present

Tags: javascript, django, ember.js, django-templates

Is there a way to get the minified EmberJs JS and CSS assets, but not have the EmberJs App start?

The use case is you have a `login.html` where you'd like the User to login, and want the static assets ahead of time, so the User doesn't have to wait for them when they get redirected to the authenticated App.

The authenticated App uses a `index.html` page, which also includes the original static assets, but will make some database calls once the User is authenticated.

In this use case, we'd like for the `Login View` to use a Django form, so `login.html` is a Django template.

If this is not possible, would the alternative be to use an EmberJs `Login View`, and force a page refresh when the User gets redirected, so as to trigger the Django database calls once in the App?

Comment: I'd love to recommend https://github.com/tildeio/ember-cli-fastboot but it is not just there yet https://github.com/tildeio/ember-cli-fastboot/issues/98

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your Ember App is a Ember-CLI project so you have to disable autoRun in the `ember-cli-build.js`. It should look something like this:

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    autoRun: false
  });
  return app.toTree();
};
```

Now the app won't get started automatically. You can boot up the app manually like this: `require("app-name/app")["default"].create({/* app settings */});`

You can also find this information in the [ember-cli user guides](http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#integration)